# how can I make the original list passed though the function and modified, but don't return a new list instead add on to old list?

Tags: python, list, function

list outputs 4, 16, 36 but should be outputting 2, 4, 6, 4, 16, 36 a combined list of my original numbers and new numbers if i take the old ones and **2.

```
def squareEach(nums):
    
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        
        nums [i] = nums[i]**2

def test ():
    
    nums = [2,4,6]
    
    squareEach(nums)
    
    print("List:", nums)

test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `append` to, or `extend`, the list.

```
>>> def append_squares(nums):
...     nums.extend([n ** 2 for n in nums])
...
>>> nums = [2, 4, 6]
>>> append_squares(nums)
>>> nums
[2, 4, 6, 4, 16, 36]
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment was very helpful i tried append before i post the question but i see now i was implementing it wrong but extend never crossed my mind. You're the man

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `nums[i] = nums[i]**2`, do `nums.append(nums[i]**2)`

Comment: thank you, your comment was very helpful to and a clear cut answer.